# Fill in the blanks

Tags: word-usage

English is not my native language. I came across this question in a tutorial video. The tutor gave option 4 as answer ,but I think the answer is option 5. Am I correct?.

Q)The Budget announced substantial _______ of ________ to critical sectors like education and healthcare.

Options

1. expenditure, capital
2. sanction, initiative
3. allotment, security
4. disbursement, investment
5. allocation, resources

Comment: Is the comma before _of_ in the original question?

Comment: Well, the comma doesn't belong there.  Several of the answers fit, but none perfectly.

Comment: A poorly constructed question that admits of several justifiable answers rather than only one. I would rank the alternatives from best to worst  as 5, 4, 1. The others are nonsense. The comma is otiose, as is the tutor.

Comment: @KillingTime, Hot Licks,Anton Thanks. Comma was a mistake from my side.

Comment: (5) certainly works. Idiomaticity is hard to judge with offbeat statements from financial institutions etc. If you came out with (4) in a crowded room (remember those?), most Anglophones would give you a strange look.

Comment: @Anton your comment looks like an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps (5) is considered incorrect as "allocation" is more normally a countable noun.

> ... substantial allocations of resources to ...

But while (4) might be grammatically sound, but the collocation of "disbursement of investment to someone" means paying them the money from the fund,

> After disbursement of investment to a client, it is the sole duty of the disbursing branch to monitor the investment...

It's not about budgeting, so (4) is meaningless, as far as I can tell (and I did need to look up the words and context so you would need specialist financial knowledge, not testing English). Disbursement is the actual release of money, not a plan or budget

I don't think "expenditure...to.. sectors" is the common structure. You would use expenditure in...

> ... substantial expenditure of capital in critical sectors...

So, after all, it's a bad test, with no correct answers.